# Vuetify - Only import UI components

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I have an existing medium-to-big size Vue3 project, and I'm looking to migrate my UI components to something more material design oriented.

I'd like to integrate Vuetify with my app, but I would rather not have to use the whole layout system of Vuetify and have to rewrite most of my app from scratch.

[Vuetify FAQs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#questions) say:

> Vuetify requires the use of the v-app component. It should wrap your
> entire application and is the center point for much of the framework
> functionality including themes. Ensure that you are following the
> proper markup documented in the Application page.

I don't see any discussion on importing single components from the library. Is there a way I can only import the Vuetify components I need (buttons, text inputs, chips, etc.) and use them inside my existing layout without having to give up all control over my app's UI to Vuetify?

Comment: This is not possible - UI components use opinionated HTML and rely on some Vuetify-specific CSS classes (e.g. for margins and paddings). Quasar behaves in the same way. Your best bet is to use some headless UI library -  e.g. https://headlessui.com/ If you insist on using Vuetify (you can import single components with `import {VButton} from "vuetify/lib"`- you will have to override some CSS styles but don't expect to achieve exactly the same look as your existing UI.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I'm kinda stubborn on using Vuetify is it seems like it's the only good material design library for vue. I know there are other component libraries but none I've tried achieves that material look Vuetify has. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: Quasar feels more robust than Vuetify and supports Vue 3 since months - but again it is opinionated and you will have to fight with the CSS overrides. There is some room for overriding (I can show you a `before` look with the standard Vuetify CSS and `after` with some CSS overrides) - but you won't be able to match any given design with Vuetify. If you are looking for Material look and feel - simply refactor your app to use only Vuetify components. If you don't want to lose control - I'm afraid you will have a tough decision ...